# Request to Kerberos authenticated API considered unauthorized despite having kerberos ticket in authorization header

Tags: apache-2.4, python, kerberos, flask

I am trying to call a Flask API endpoint (http://monarch.example.com:8080/) hosted in Apache web server in a Linux machine. This endpoint is protected by Kerberos authentication. I use `kinit user` to initialize Kerberos.

Then I am using python kerberos library to get the ticket and requests library for the api call. I am providing the ticket in the Authorization header of the request. Relevant code snippet for that:

```
`__, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP@monarch.example.com")
kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
auth_header = ("Negotiate " + kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(krb_context))
headers = {"Authorization": auth_header}`
```

I have checked that the Authorization header is populated with a value.

However I get 401-unauthorized as response.

The Kerberos configuration from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/monarch.conf` for the Service containing the endpoint  is:

```
<Directory /var/www/monarch>
       AuthType Kerberos
       AuthName "Acme Corporation"
       KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
       KrbMethodNegotiate Off
       KrbSaveCredentials Off
       KrbVerifyKDC Off
       KrbMethodK5Passwd On
       # Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/http.keytab
       Krb5keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
       Require user user@EXAMPLE.COM
</Directory>
```

Lastly, the list of principals is:

```
host/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
HTTP/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
K/M@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/changepw@EXAMPLE.COM
krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
user@EXAMPLE.COM
root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
```

I have been stuck with this problem for a few days now. It would be great if anyone can help me in this regard.

Comment: Apparently this is cross-posted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240792/request-to-kerberos-authenticated-api-considered-unauthorized-despite-having-ker